# Check if Email exist, element does not find function

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework

I just started out with Agular and C# and trying to check if an email already exist in database.

When Im checking i get this error in the console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: EmailCheck is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (consult:1)
```

This is how it's setup :

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckEmailAvailability(string userdata)
 {
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
   var SearchData = db.ConsultList.Where(x => x.Email == 
       userdata).SingleOrDefault();
   if(SearchData != null)
   {
    return Json(1);
   }
   else
   {
     return Json(0);
   }
 }
```

**consult.component.html**

```
<div>
   <span>Email</span>
   <input type="text" id="Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" formControlName="Email" onchange="EmailCheck()">
</div>
<div>
   <p id="Status"></p>
</div>



<script>

    function EmailCheck() {
        $("#Status").html("Checking...");
        $.post("@Url.Action("
            CheckEmailAvailability ", "
            Consult ")", {
                userdata: $("#Email").val()
            },
            function (data) {
                if (data == 0) {
                    $("#Status").html('<font color="Green">Email Available');
                    $("#Email").css("border-color", "Green");
                    else {
                        $("#Status").html('<font color="Red">Email is already in use</font>');
                        $("#Email").css("border-color", "Red");
                    }
                });
        }  

 </script>
```

I have tried multiple ways to get it to work, but I don't really understand why the element does not find the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not familiar with Angular, but if I had to venture a guess, which this is, I'd say your script isn't being generated at the right level. Check the DOM in your browser and see if you even see that script. If it were a razor page I'd say wrap it inside of `@section scripts` to make sure it gets to the right level, but I have no idea what the right thing is for Angular if that's even in the right direction.

Comment: @gilliduck indeed!. The script is not being loaded. Will try call the javascript from another file.

Comment: once you get it working, answer your own question unless someone provides an answer. I know nothing of Angular so I can't provide an answer, just that general bit of guidance. Best of luck.

Comment: yes, unfortunately is still hustling.